# .htaccess internal redirect not working with string parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So i have been on this for hours but can't get it to resolve. Nothing on stackoverflow tackles my issue. The issue is that i have a redirect rule in my .htaccess as follows

```
RewriteRule ^store-category/(.+)/?$ /wordpress/store-category/?cid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This redirect works when cid is a number but when a use a string like **"my-key"** it does not work. With the key i have to change the rule to this.

```
RewriteRule ^store-category/(.+)/?$ /wordpress/store-category/?cid=$1 [R,L]
```

However i do not want to use this because this redirects my users visibly and the url changes, which i don't want. Can anyone please explain why this thing is working for numbers but not for string parameters. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Complete .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^store-category/(.+)/?$ /wordpress/store-category/?cid=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is this the only rule in your .htaccess file?

Comment: no. It is a standard wordpress .htaccess with this additional rule

Comment: is it possible that the redirect is happening but the script receiving the request is expecting a number not a string and is therefore failing?

Comment: there is no such issue. It gives page not found error.

Comment: can you post the other rules from the .htaccess file please

Comment: It's not possible to find the culprit by looking at some rules which seem to be correct. You should set up a log level to check what's going on `LogLevel rewrite:trace3`

Comment: Can you please confirm the location of your `.htaccess` file... from your directives I assume this is in the `/wordpress` subdirectory? ie. `/wordpress/.htaccess`?

Comment: It is where is should be by default. In the same directory as wp-config, wp-content

Comment: Wordpress CMS system doesn't work well with rewrite rules. You will need to use [Wordpress rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) for this.

Comment: I am using WordPress rewrite API i did not write it in .htaccess

Comment: Its possible that if you have special characters in the url, then on redirection, it get getting url encoded and giving a 404 (try with the NE flag)

Comment: What string are you trying to go to? Are there any strange characters in there?

Comment: Does changing your wildcard from `(.+)` to `(.*)` fix your issue?

Comment: There is no such string. It contains only alphabet. It won't work with even writing 'what'.

Comment: Changing (.+) to (.*) gives 500 error.

Comment: What is `/store-category/`? Is it a custom taxonomy?

Comment: it is slug of a page

Answer (score 1):

I did some try on local and found that it works for me if I put these two rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

even before the row

```
RewriteRule ^store-category/(.+)/?$ /wordpress/store-category/?cid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Complete `.htaccess` file will be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^store-category/(.+)/?$ /wordpress/store-category/?cid=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anyway, with `(.+)/?$`, an eventual trailing slash will be captured from the group and will go on the `cid` parameters. If categories doesn't have slashes inside, it's better to use `([^/]+)/?$`.

**Update**: The understand what happen on your redirects, enable the log (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html fo this). On my host I enabled `mod_rewrite.c:trace3` and I get the following log in `error_log` (just tracking lines with `rewrite`)

```
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904099 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/store-category/my-id -> store-category/my-id
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904123 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'store-category/my-id'
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904129 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/store-category/my-id -> store-category/my-id
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904132 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] applying pattern '^store-category/(.+)/?$' to uri 'store-category/my-id'
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904143 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] rewrite 'store-category/my-id' -> '/wordpress/store-category/?cid=my-id'
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904147 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] split uri=/wordpress/store-category/?cid=my-id -> uri=/wordpress/store-category/, args=cid=my-id
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904151 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/ with /wordpress/
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904155 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] trying to replace context docroot /var/www/localhost/htdocs with context prefix 
[Fri Aug 04 12:48:56.904158 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 22823:tid 140368028878592] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client ::1:58312] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#788520][rid#7fa9e4002970/initial] [perdir /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wordpress/] internal redirect with /wordpress/store-category/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

(followed by some other logging while it try to find the default document `index.php`)

Comment: @shazyriver can you access to the apache log and activate logging for mod_rewrite? (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for this)

Comment: `httpd.conf` or some file imported by it (on my PC I have it in `/etc/apache2/modules.d/00_default_settings.conf` but it depends on your system)

Comment: too much info in the log. Can't get a clue :(

Comment: check only lines that contains `rewrite`. I update post with my log as it doesn't allow me to post it in the comments.

Comment: I did. They do not give me a clue.

Comment: Please, add your log to your request. Maybe it will be useful to help you

Answer (score 0):

Regex is greedy (left to right). You're pulling in extra slashes possibly other things. I find it easiest to use not classes for URLs (rarely '.' which will match everything).

```
RewriteRule ^store-category/([^\/]+)/?$ store-category/?cid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You may also be able to simplify to this, depending on how you want to handle urls that may be malformed after the store category id.

```
RewriteRule ^store-category/([^\/]+) store-category/?cid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

EDIT: You are right. I didn't test the whole htaccess. You're specifying the wordpress path twice one in rewritebase and again in the rule. I have updated the rules above, as well as providing a link to the updated solution in a tester:

http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=116de701-cf8a-577c-bab5-5c357d844452

Comment: This still does not affect the outcome

Comment: Thank you very much. But i did not write this rule. I used the wordpress function to automatically generate it. And using a number it works. So i don't think it has anything to do with wordpress path twice reason.